# Turning array of JSON objects into an array for HighCharts/GoogleCharts

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I've done a lot of searching and I just can't seem to wrap my head around how to convert this:

```
[
   {"id":749,"time":20160416162403,"value":707},
   {"id":750,"time":20160416162407,"value":708},
   {"id":751,"time":20160416162411,"value":703},
   {"id":752,"time":20160416162415,"value":710}
]
```

Into something HighCharts or GoogleCharts can use such as a series:

```
name: []
time: [time1, time2, time3]
```

I've seen examples that were close that used JQuery but I can't seem to get it working.  If anyone could provide a quick example/solution I can run with it from there.

Thanks for the edit GG, I'll try to format it correctly next time.

Comment: What server-side technology are you using, if any? Depending on it, you can format the output to the format expected at HighCharts.

Comment: is 'id' something you want to be displayed in the chart?

Comment: I'm doing this on a beaglebone using temperature and light sensors.  I've written the webserver in Node.JS and I'm using SQLite3 as my database.  Everything has been written in JavaScript and no framework has been used.  Please let me know if you need any code examples.  id is simply a placeholder for the autoincrement feature of the database.  I don't use id in any of my queries.

Comment: What I don't understand is, if you made the server output (the server being node.js and javascript, I know), why didn't you output it the way highcharts expected? Or is that output coming directly from one of the sensors?

Comment: That said, I believe you can treat the object using pure javascript (albeit a not-so-short code, if my proeficiency isn't betraying me). I'll see if I can cough up a code and post it as an answer :)

Comment: The output is like that due to the way SQLite3 returns the data.  The queries return the data as an array of JSON objects.  I could not figure out a way to output the data in a way that HighCharts would agree with so I figured I would take the data I have and transform it.  Thank you Eric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same as Jeffrey's approach, only using pure javascript (in a marginally less appropriate manner).

```
var sensorOutput = [
      {"id":749,"time":20160416162403,"value":707},
      {"id":750,"time":20160416162407,"value":708},
      {"id":751,"time":20160416162411,"value":703},
      {"id":752,"time":20160416162415,"value":710}
   ];

//Here I declare an output class; 
var outputClass = function()
{
    this.name='';
    this.time = [];
};

function convertOutput(inputArray)
{
    //Here I instantiate the class
    var output = new outputClass();

    //And here I populate its array with the input received from the sensors.
    for(var x=0; x< inputArray.length; x++)
    {
        var sensorOutputLine = inputArray[x];
        var currentTime = sensorOutputLine.time;
        output.time.push(currentTime); //Push the item into the time[] array
    }
}

//Function call 
convertOutput(sensorOutput);
```

This is the code I'd come up with at the first time. If you're considering using it, consider improving it :)

The JsBin is here: https://jsbin.com/mixasihibe/edit?html,js,output

**EDIT:** Improved the readability of the code... As bored as boredom means xD

Comment: Thanks Eric I'm going to try both approaches and see how it goes.

Comment: I was able to get your code to work without modifications.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

I think you could just build a simple constructor for it:

```
var jsonObj = [
   {"id":749,"time":20160416162403,"value":707},
   {"id":750,"time":20160416162407,"value":708},
   {"id":751,"time":20160416162411,"value":703},
   {"id":752,"time":20160416162415,"value":710}
]
var highChartsObj = {
    time: [],
    value: []
}
$.each( jsonObj , function( key, val ) {
    highChartsObj.time.push(val.time)
    highChartsObj.value.push(val.value)
});
```

[Here's a Fiddle for it](https://jsfiddle.net/alphanerds/mnw7ns3L/1/)

Comment: And THAT's why I need to return to javascript. 
Took me 10 minutes what you did in 5. :<

Comment: Can you +1 it for me. Glad it helped :)

Comment: Jeffrey thank you, I'm working it into my code right now to test it out.  I'll be sure to +1 and best answer it here shortly.

Comment: Jeffrey I'm having a bit of trouble getting the code to work.  It appears that I had a JSON.stringify(databasereturn) in my code and that's the reason it is formed that way.  The raw return from the database is this: `[ { time: 20160416174725 },
  { time: 20160416174729 },
  { time: 20160416174733 } ]`  Is this a problem for the above solution?